# How to set preferred language in Geb using firefox driver?

Tags: firefox, geb

I wrote a small geb script to test my web app using firefox and it works fine. Now I want to change the preferred language settings in firefox inside the script to 'en' rather than 'de' which is the default preferred language in my firefox.

```
    Browser.drive {
        setBaseUrl(myBaseUrl)
        to CreatePage
        fillPersonalData(page)

        page.nextButton.click()

        page CreatePage
        verifyAt()
    }.clearCookies()
```

How can I do this to test my web app using a firefox set to english language prefered?

Answer (score 1):

In `GebConfig.groovy`:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.*

driver = {
    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile()
    profile.setPreference("intl.accept_languages", "en")
    new FirefoxDriver(profile)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to erdi's answer, if you want to change local during a test instead of doing so in the config, you can do:

```
browser.driver.quit()
FirefoxProfile fp = new FirefoxProfile()
fp.setPreference("intl.accept_languages", "en")
browser.driver = new org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver(fp)
```

Which will reopen the browser with the new language setting.